# postfix not substituting %s

Tags: mysql, postfix-mta

Postfix 3.1.4 on Debian Stretch appears to be failing to substitute the address it's attempting to resolve with mysql_table.

I have /etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf configured (below), but it never authenticates. When I check the MySQL log table, I see:

```
| 2017-08-28 23:19:54 | postfix[postfix] @ localhost [127.0.0.1] |       834 |         0 | Query        | START TRANSACTION                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
| 2017-08-28 23:19:54 | postfix[postfix] @ localhost [127.0.0.1] |       834 |         0 | Query        | SELECT password FROM mailbox WHERE username = '%s'                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
| 2017-08-28 23:19:54 | postfix[postfix] @ localhost [127.0.0.1] |       834 |         0 | Query        | SELECT password FROM mailbox WHERE username = '%s'                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
| 2017-08-28 23:19:54 | postfix[postfix] @ localhost [127.0.0.1] |       834 |         0 | Query        | COMMIT
```

When `%s` is a postfix template, not a MySQL / MariaDB one. It should be filling in the email address, or the user here, but it appears to just be copying this from the configs verbatim.

Here is the content of /etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf:

```
autheck_method: saslauthd
mech_list: plain login
allow_plaintext: true
auxprop_plugin: sql
sql_hostnames: 127.0.0.1
sql_user: [redacted]
sql_passwd:  [redacted]
sql_database:  [redacted]
sql_select: SELECT password FROM mailbox WHERE username = '%s'
log_level:10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this works: `select password from users where email = '%u@%r'`, but %s does not.